# Why can't I add information to List's Updates By?

Tags: 2013, list

Why am I unable to add information to the new columns labeled Updates by within a List Item?

I noticed even after I uploaded a file to that List Item the Updates By did not register anything in the field.

[image]

Comment: what's the type of this field ?

Comment: I'm not even sure. That's a good question.

Comment: Try by adding the field by making the list in quick edit mode. Will help to get the type of column

Comment: There is already a CreatedBy and ModifiedBy field. Why not use those??

Answer (score -2):

I think this is the "Updated By" column, which is an internal SharePoint column, ergo, non-editable. You could verify this by updating one of the items in your list, and the "Updated By" column will be set to the value of whichever user made the update

Comment: So Should you tell me  what is the diff between Updated By and Modified By ?

Comment: I tried that by uploading a file. The "Updated By" column did not list my name. It remained blank.

Comment: Now edit the file and re-save. That wasn't a modification, it was an initial upload